# How typescript internally handles encapsulation, inheritance and data hiding?

Tags: javascript, typescript2.0, transpiler

I am curious to explore and understand the typescript to es5 transpilation process. I am pretty clear on the part how typescript uses closures to create scopes and managing inheritance, what still surprises me on the fact that how exactly typescript implements private data members and encapsulation as in the compiled ES5, I don't see any difference between the private and public data member scope. How exactly typescripts handles privacy internally?
What exactly is it doing for prototype inheritance (var __extends)?

Here is the link to the typescript playground, I am experimenting on:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Shape%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20shapeType%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name%20%2C%20shapeType)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.shapeType%20%3D%20shapeType%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Triangle%20extends%20Shape%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name%2C%20shapeType)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(name%20%2C%20shapeType)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D

Typescript:

```
class Shape{
    private name: string;
    public shapeType: string;

    constructor(name , shapeType) {
        this.name = name;
        this.shapeType = shapeType;
    }

}

class Triangle extends Shape{
    constructor(name, shapeType) {
        super(name , shapeType);
    }
}
```

Transpiled JS:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
        ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
        function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var Shape = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Shape(name, shapeType) {
        this.name = name;
        this.shapeType = shapeType;
    }
    return Shape;
}());
var Triangle = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(Triangle, _super);
    function Triangle(name, shapeType) {
        return _super.call(this, name, shapeType) || this;
    }
    return Triangle;
}(Shape));
```

Comment: Privacy is a not a runtime thing, it's just static.

Comment: "How exactly typescripts handles privacy internally?" --- it does not. Typescript only exists compile time. After all compile checks have passed - there is no difference between private and public members.

Comment: [The private in TypeScript is kinda private](https://yakovfain.com/2015/06/30/the-private-in-typescript-is-kinda-private/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The privacy of members are only enforced within typescript itself. So they are "private" only in typescript for convinience. While in typescript the compiler just checks if the property is private but once transpiled a private property is a just regular property.

If you are interested in making something private in JS, you can refer to [Emulating private methods with closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Emulating_private_methods_with_closures)

Comment: So once it is transpiled, one I directly changed it's property in JS, like a regular property?

Comment: Yes it is private only in the context of typescript and the typescript compiler checks if it is private. But in the output(so the JS) it is a normal property and you could change it from outside if you edited the script.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Though I am figuring out next is how exactly it is implementing inheritance. Thanks for the help

Comment: If the answer helped you, you can accept it(check the checkmark on the left - this will give you 2 reputation) or upvote it.

Comment: Thanks mdatsev. Could you also help me understand how exactly __extends is handled and what exactly is it doing?

Comment: I haven't really examined how it works so I can't help you here but you don't really need to know. Just use typescript for typechecking and it will handle the rest itself.